# How Can I use Remotipart 1.0 with Rails 3.2 to save file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I have this form

```
<%= form_for @post, :html => {:multipart => true , :class => 'form-horizontal' }, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title%>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar%>
    <%= f.submit nil%>
<% end %>
```

and the `create` action as well

```
def create
        @post = Post.new(params[:post])
        respond_to do |format|
          if @post.save
            format.js
          end
        end
      end
```

whatever I write in `create.js.erb` it doesn't run, and the browser is redirected to white page!

```
$('body').html("<h1>Done!</h1>");
```

Can anyone tell me what's the problem here?
Note that I followed the documentation example steps on [github](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart)

Comment: Probably your app is responding to HTML, it's the same problem I'm having right now.. You can check it by removing the file_field, and the :multipart => true option, if it's rendering the create.js, thats your problem.. And if I'm right, the multipart option is auto added when adding a file_field, but I'm not sure..

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure

```
//= require jquery.remotipart
```

Is added to your application.js file. I was having the same problem and this fixed it.